# Is it possible to consume a web service in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I am pretty new to asp.net MVC.  I am using MVC3 and I was wondering if it is possible to have web services as my models.  I know that in MVC, your views for create, delete, edit and details are auto generated but in a web service, it will be one view per web service.  Is what I am trying to accomplish weird?  Is that not really the point of using MVC?  I am having a hard time finding any examples which makes me think that I am using the wrong technology here. Accepted answer will be one with a link to a nice tutorial or a good explanation with an example.  My main concern is doing extra work when things can be auto generated.  So I've added the web reference and can I create my controller and auto generate some stuff with this reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can consume web services in ASP.NET MVC. In this case your models will be the classes that were imported from the web service when you generated the client proxy. But no matter where your models come from you should always define view models which are classes that are specifically tailored to the requirements of your views. Then you will have your controller actions pass view models to the views, not models. The controller action will be responsible of querying the data source in order to retrieve a model (this data source could be absolutely anything imaginable), map the model to the view model class and pass this view model to the view.